# "This app has no Android key hashses configured. Configure your app key hashes at ~~

Tags: android, firebase, facebook-login

I tried to use Facebook login in my app.
But I have this problem only on my physical android device. (not a virtual device)

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup the key hash in the facebook App Dashboard. To get the signature key hash,
just call the method below in your App in a release build (no publishing required) and run your app - in Logcat you can see the output.
After this you can remove the method.
If you want it also to work for debugging purposes do the same in a debug release. Because the hashes are different.

```
private void printKeyHash()  {
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName() , PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for(Signature signature:info.signatures){
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.i("Signature", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));// <--- signature
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In Facebook App Dashboard enter the hashes. And don't forget to switch the App Mode to live after your app is released

[image: Facebook App Dashboard]

Comment: I could solve my problem this way, Thank you :)

Comment: Thats's great. I would appreciate if you mark the answer as accepted :)